# How To: Encapsulate CustomKeyBoard in its own class, so it can be used in several VCs?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, encapsulation

I modified the NumPad, Apple provides, by using the left down space as a period button. It all works fine, no question concerning that.

I want to encapsulate the methods in their own class, so I don't need to implement them for every viewController, but I don't now how to do that, as overriding the methods doesn't seem to work (or at least [super theMethod] doesn't), and I also work with Notifications (UIKeyboardDidShowNotification) and.. well.. I'd need a little help on that..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This may sound silly, but did you try creating a shared superclass for your view controller?
You can put all your shared stuff together in the superclass and use them in the subclasses simply calling the methods on self. You should only take care of calling where you override some implementation.
If you have already tried this way please ignore this message.